# //cannot get, node js dont like my files other dust file

Tags: node.js

Hello im trying to get my node.js to work, however my site only renders one page and thats my index file? why is that? I tried to load my other page with app.get and then render it but it doesn't work..

```
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'img')));

app.get('/'), function(req, res){
    res.render('behandlare');  //cant i load like this?!?!
}


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){

pool.connect(function(err, services, done){ 
    if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching services from table', err);
    }
    services.query('SELECT * FROM public.services', function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return console.error('error runnig query', err);
        }
        res.render('index', {services: result.rows});
        done();
    });
});
});
```

both are in views folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('behandlare');
})
```

You have written a wrong syntax for callback. Try this and do check whether your syntax are correct each time

Comment: hmm it works but now my index file doesn't work, why is that?

Comment: There might be something wrong with your query. I give you one more suggestion. Better use Async/Await instead of using callback. It makes your code more clean and structured also you can catch error more easily.